# Firefox pageMod addon window.location isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I'm building a Firefox Add-on that causes page redirects to happen after keyboard buttons are pressed. The keyboard detection is working just fine, but it just doesn't redirect. The full code is hosted on [GitHub](https://raw.github.com/kobitate94/keyaffinity/master/Chrome/background.js) (it says the Chrome version but it all Javascript for now). The redirect code in question is also included below. All the code I've ported to Firefox is working just fine in Chrome, so all the Javascript is valid.

```
// Function that does the redirecting
function goToMsgs() {
    if (newNotes){
        window.location = "/msg/pms";
    }
    else if (newSubs) {
        window.location = "/msg/submissions";
    }
    else if (newComms) {
        window.location = "/msg/others";
    }
    else if (newTix) {
        window.location = "/msg/troubletickets";
    }
    else {
        $('#keyaffinity-nomsgs').fadeIn(100).delay(500).fadeOut(100);
    }
}

// And the keyboard shortcut that triggers it, this still triggers,according to the logs
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {                
    // Code omitted
    else if (event.keyCode == 77 && control) {                      
        goToMsgs();                                                 
    }
    // Code omitted
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add full URL for it so Add this things to your code and then check it.

```
        var StrArr = 'http://'+window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
        // Use full URL here
        window.location.href = StrArr + '/msg/pms';
```

Comment: That did not work. I also added in an alert to ensure that the if statement code is triggering and it is.

Comment: Since the addon is site-specific, I just change it to have the full URL. I couldn't get what you posted to work properly. It would go to http// not http://

Answer (score 0):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) seems to recommend assigning simply to `window.location`, rather than `window.location.href`.